# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager' (.Net Core 2.0 with EF4)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting exception **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'** for following code

```
       try
        {
            Employee oEmployee = new Employee();
            using (var ctx = new HelloContext())
            {
                //something
            }
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Is HelloContext in a .NET Framework DLL?

Answer (score 2):

As a part of moving form xml configuration to json configuation , the asp.net core no longer  recommends storing coniguration in **app.config**, instead they are recommending to use a json file **appsettings.json**.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?highlight=settings&tabs=basicconfiguration) is the official documentation which I always suggest as a must read.

Comment: if to be more correct, the ASP.NET Core team doesn't directly recommend to use the `appsettings.json` file. Instead, they encourage to use the Configuration API and register a suitable configuration provider. And one of the built-in providers is a JSON provider that can read settings from JSON file (which name by convention is `appsettings.json`).